# Shadow is displayed in the android studio preview but not on the android device

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add shadows to my images on an `activity`. The shadow is displayed on the view of the android studio but it isn't showing on my android device. I tried an android 4.4.2 and an android 6.0 but the problem persists. I enabled `HardwareAccelerated` in the manifest file.

Here is a bit of the my `xml` code of the image:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/category_layout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/map_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/home_bar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/notification_layout"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/category_image"
        app:rv_zoom="true"
        app:rv_zoomScale="1.06"
        app:rv_zoomDuration="400"
        app:rv_alpha="180"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/shop_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/image_shadow"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"

        />
    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Category"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:shadowColor="#90000000"
        android:shadowDx="3.0"
        android:shadowDy="3.0"
        android:shadowRadius="3.0"
        android:padding="3dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I tried using the paddings on parent and set clipToPadding to false.
This is the xml code of the image_shadow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#90000000"/>
</shape>
```

**And this is an image of the display in the android studio preview:**

[image]

This is the display on my device Android 4.4.2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NgqG.png)

Comment: could you post the real device screenshot as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added a screenshot of the display on the android device.